# asp.net databind gridview with vertical scrollbar

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

i have some long data in my gridview and need a scrollbar (to the gridview). 
try few ways - non of them works.
i guess because the postback or the databind..

the asp.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGuess" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="gvGuess_RowDataBound" Style="top: 301px; left: 212px; direction: rtl; overflow:scroll; position: absolute; height: 176px; width: 359px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None">

 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
           <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

and the c# code:

```
    protected void loadGuess()
    {
  noInfo.Visible = false;
  ds = dataFunk.getGuestsgrid(Convert.ToString(Session["orderNum"]),    Convert.ToString(Session["choice"]));
        gvGuess.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gvGuess.DataSource = ds;
        gvGuess.DataMember = dataFunk.getGuestsgrid(Convert.ToString(Session["orderNum"]), Convert.ToString(Session["choice"])).Tables[0].ToString();
            gvGuess.DataBind();}
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

some time ago i stuck at same. I tried a work around and it work for me.

Wrap your gridview in a div and give dive a definite height with overflow-y:scroll
something like this

```
<div id="popup" style="max-height:600px;overflow-y:scroll;">
 // Your GridView
</div>
```

this will work like sliding Gridview. you can give max-height as you like.

Comment: don't give height of your gridview, give height only of div than try, it should work

Comment: How do you do this if i t is in a row in a grid as it complains that HTML5 complains div cannot be nested in element tr.

Answer (score 0):

**For vertical and horizontal scroll bar with height**

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">your GridView</div>
```